# New to HTML/CSS navbar get rid of whitespace

Tags: html, navigationbar

Hello I am just getting started with HTML and CSS but having a weird issue.

If I use border:0; and padding:0; I still get a white space all the way around my div.  I can fix the issue by doing margin:-8; but that doesn't seem right to me.  I am using Dreamweaver if that matters.  thanks!

```
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">Home - Introduction - Stakeholders - Implementation Plan - Proposal - Training</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#navbar {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #CCC;
height: 25px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #000;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a page where you have this?  I don't have any issues with white space.  Are you only seeing it within Dreamweaver?  (I hate Dreamweaver...)

Comment: Hmm so adding this to the CSS sheet fixed my problem.  Is this the correct way to do this?  Does this mean that every body in every html page that is linked to the CSS will have 0 margins on the body?

    body {
    margin:0;
    }

Comment: Yes, any page including your style sheet with have a body margin of 0 this way.  You may want to look into getting a CSS reset sheet.  People include that style sheet prior to any other in case there are browsers with different defaults for certain elements.

Comment: Yes I found the reset sheet.  Should all of the info in the reset sheet be above my actual CSS sheet for my site?  It looks like it basically takes every possible element in CSS and resets it to 0.

Comment: Well, pretty much.  But yes, if you wanted to use it, it would go above the link to your current style sheet.

Comment: Ahh you can link 2 style sheets?  I didn't know that. Also if I set a style by using body {margin:0;} and then change the margin in the same style sheet with #navbar{margin:5;} will my navbar div have the margin value of 5 or does setting the body style overwrite everything else below it?

Comment: Setting the body's margin to 0 will set anything else that automatically inherits the margin of the body tag to 0 as well.  However, the style sheet is also read from top to bottom, meaning that as long as you set the margin to #navbar below the margin to body, it will not be overwritten by the body's margin whether it naturally inherits it's margin attribute or not.  :)

Comment: Got it thanks James I appreciate the information.

Comment: No problem. :)  Oh, and yes to your earlier question.  You can have more than 1 style sheet.  I think it's actually unlimited.  In some of my sites, I have around 4 style sheets.  One for the general layout, one for forms, one for print, etc.

Comment: I would suggest using a table with `<a href=""> links instead. Like <ul><li id=""><a href=""></a></li></ul>`....

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks!

Adding a body tag in my CSS and setting the margins to auto fixed this.